Can't update firmware - Secure boot is enabled, but shim isn't installed to EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
Hi guys I have installed ubuntu with the experimental full hardware backed encryption (learn more here).
When I try to update firmware:
itsme@Laptop:~$ fwupdmgr update
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • Integrated Webcam FHD
 • TPM
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • BG6 KIOXIA 512GB
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Upgrade System Firmware from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0?                                 ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ This stable release fixes the following issues: Initial BIOS release for     ║
║ Latitude 5550,Precision 3590,Precision 3591 MTL.                             ║
║                                                                              ║
║ Latitude 5550 must remain plugged into a power source for the duration of    ║
║ the update to avoid damage.                                                  ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
Perform operation? [Y|n]: y
Decompressing…           [                                       ]
Secure boot is enabled, but shim isn't installed to EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

Someone told me to install this but I get:
itsmeagain@Laptop:~$ sudo apt install shim-signed
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 boot-managed-by-snapd : Conflicts: grub-efi-amd64-signed but 1.202+2.12-1ubuntu7 is to be installed
                         Conflicts: shim-signed but 1.58+15.8-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
 grub-efi-amd64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64 but it is not going to be installed or
                                  grub-pc but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: secureboot-db but it is not going to be installed

Cannot install grub-efi-amd64-signed on system as boot is managed by snapd.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

I'm new to ubuntu, how to fix this please?
Here are more info you might need
Device Security Report
======================

Report details
  Date generated:                                  2024-07-26 15:11:51
  fwupd version:                                   1.9.16

System details
  Hardware model:                                  Dell Inc. Latitude 5550
  Processor:                                       Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 165U
  OS:                                              Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
  Security level:                                  HSI:0! (v1.9.16)

HSI-1 Tests
  UEFI Platform Key:                               Pass (Valid)
  TPM v2.0:                                        Pass (Found)
  UEFI Bootservice Variables:                      Pass (Locked)
  Firmware BIOS Region:                            Pass (Locked)
  MEI Key Manifest:                                Pass (Valid)
  UEFI Secure Boot:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Firmware Write Protection Lock:                  Pass (Enabled)
  Platform Debugging:                              Pass (Not Enabled)
  Intel Management Engine Manufacturing Mode:      Pass (Locked)
  BIOS Firmware Updates:                           Pass (Enabled)
  Firmware Write Protection:                       Pass (Not Enabled)
  TPM Platform Configuration:                      Pass (Valid)
  Intel Management Engine Override:                Pass (Locked)
  Intel Management Engine Version:               ! Fail 

HSI-2 Tests
  Platform Debugging:                              Pass (Locked)
  Intel BootGuard ACM Protected:                 ! Fail (Not Valid)
  IOMMU Protection:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Intel BootGuard Fuse:                            Pass (Valid)
  BIOS Rollback Protection:                      ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  Intel BootGuard Verified Boot:                 ! Fail (Not Valid)
  TPM Reconstruction:                              Pass (Valid)
  Intel BootGuard:                                 Pass (Enabled)

HSI-3 Tests
  Suspend To RAM:                                  Pass (Not Enabled)
  Intel BootGuard Error Policy:                  ! Fail (Not Valid)
  Pre-boot DMA Protection:                         Pass (Enabled)
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:             Pass (Supported)
  Suspend To Idle:                                 Pass (Enabled)

HSI-4 Tests
  Encrypted RAM:                                 ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  Supervisor Mode Access Prevention:               Pass (Enabled)

Runtime Tests
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:           ! Fail (Not Supported)
  Firmware Updater Verification:                   Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Swap:                                      Pass (Encrypted)
  Linux Kernel Verification:                       Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Kernel Lockdown:                           Pass (Enabled)

Host security events

For information on the contents of this report, see https://fwupd.github.io/hsi.html

Also
yetmeagain@Laptop:~$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* UEFI BG6 KIOXIA 512GB 2E9CTGYGZ0XU 1  HD(1,GPT,61615ba8-e2c4-4d47-b2a1-16e38b88b980,0x800,0x177000)/File(\EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi){auto_created_boot_option}
      dp: 04 01 2a 00 01 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 70 17 00 00 00 00 00 a8 5b 61 61 c4 e2 47 4d b2 a1 16 e3 8b 88 b9 80 02 02 / 04 04 30 00 5c 00 45 00 46 00 49 00 5c 00 42 00 6f 00 6f 00 74 00 5c 00 42 00 6f 00 6f 00 74 00 58 00 36 00 34 00 2e 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00 / 7f ff 04 00
    data: 4e ac 08 81 11 9f 59 4d 85 0e e2 1a 52 2c 59 b2

Only thing in boot folder is
this

Can you try sudo fwupdmgr update --force -y?

@amar I get Devices with no available firmware updates:   • Integrated Webcam FHD  • TPM Devices with the latest available firmware version:  • BG6 KIOXIA 512GB Decompressing…           [                                       ] Secure boot is enabled, but shim isn't installed to EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 

I would suggest these answers check the answer from frank first if that is not it, then the answer from Benoit, but have a Ubuntu usb handy just in case.

@amar I'll happily give out 100 bounty when this is solved.
boot/efi/EFI/Boot/shimx64.efi doesn't exist for me.
check my updated post

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
