Certification issue for dell latitude 5550
So I have a dell latitude 5550 with these specs
and on the ubuntu certified laptops page for this model, the processors listed are totally different. The listed hardware doesn't even exist for the 5550 model!
So I get 
Here is the technical report
Device Security Report
======================

Report details
  Date generated:                                  2024-08-01 11:49:44
  fwupd version:                                   1.9.16

System details
  Hardware model:                                  Dell Inc. Latitude 5550
  Processor:                                       Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 165U
  OS:                                              Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
  Security level:                                  HSI:0! (v1.9.16)

HSI-1 Tests
  UEFI Platform Key:                               Pass (Valid)
  TPM v2.0:                                        Pass (Found)
  UEFI Bootservice Variables:                      Pass (Locked)
  Firmware BIOS Region:                            Pass (Locked)
  MEI Key Manifest:                                Pass (Valid)
  UEFI Secure Boot:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Firmware Write Protection Lock:                  Pass (Enabled)
  Platform Debugging:                              Pass (Not Enabled)
  Intel Management Engine Manufacturing Mode:      Pass (Locked)
  BIOS Firmware Updates:                           Pass (Enabled)
  Firmware Write Protection:                       Pass (Not Enabled)
  TPM Platform Configuration:                      Pass (Valid)
  Intel Management Engine Override:                Pass (Locked)
  Intel Management Engine Version:               ! Fail 

HSI-2 Tests
  Platform Debugging:                              Pass (Locked)
  Intel BootGuard ACM Protected:                 ! Fail (Not Valid)
  IOMMU Protection:                                Pass (Enabled)
  Intel BootGuard Fuse:                            Pass (Valid)
  BIOS Rollback Protection:                      ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  Intel BootGuard Verified Boot:                 ! Fail (Not Valid)
  TPM Reconstruction:                              Pass (Valid)
  Intel BootGuard:                                 Pass (Enabled)

HSI-3 Tests
  Suspend To RAM:                                  Pass (Not Enabled)
  Intel BootGuard Error Policy:                  ! Fail (Not Valid)
  Pre-boot DMA Protection:                         Pass (Enabled)
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:             Pass (Supported)
  Suspend To Idle:                                 Pass (Enabled)

HSI-4 Tests
  Encrypted RAM:                                 ! Fail (Not Enabled)
  Supervisor Mode Access Prevention:               Pass (Enabled)

Runtime Tests
  Control-flow Enforcement Technology:           ! Fail (Not Supported)
  Firmware Updater Verification:                   Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Swap:                                      Pass (Encrypted)
  Linux Kernel Verification:                       Pass (Not Tainted)
  Linux Kernel Lockdown:                           Pass (Enabled)

Host security events

For information on the contents of this report, see https://fwupd.github.io/hsi.html

Is my laptop doomed for ubuntu use? Or do I just wait for next ubuntu version and the ubuntu devs will fix it?

OEM certifications are made on the equipment the OEM provide for certification, which was valid/accurate at time of certification request. Its common for larger companies to change equipment during a product run (esp. if made for >3 months). If a company wanted another certification, they'd have to pay for one, which rarely happens. Certification is done purely in hopes it'll increase sales; and Ubuntu devs will only do it if the OEM submits bug reports, patches, or pays for the changes (so asking Dell maybe in order)

This question is similar to: Will my device work with Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc so the certification/software is paid by dell?
it's not the ubuntu community that fixes the ubuntu software to make it work on newer laptops?

The reason hardware doesn't pass checks is that the hardware is unsupported by ubuntu?

Certification is done by Canonical engineers when the OEM provides the hardware. It's that simple. Certification has nothing to do with the support you receive here nor the support you receive when you file a bug report. Lots of Non-Certified hardware works perfectly well with Ubuntu

The question presents hardware specs and a hardware test, then asks if software will compensate for OEM hardware deficiencies.
No, Ubuntu will not compensate for hardware deficiencies.
Ubuntu may run perfectly well on your hardware anyway. It runs on most hardware very well.
Ubuntu does not, for example, require an Intel BootGuard Error Policy in order to successfully boot and operate.

you say ubuntu runs perfectly on most hardware yet I'm asking this question because I couldn't update my firmware and I suspect it was due to the hardware not being certified
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1521529/cant-update-firmware-secure-boot-is-enabled-but-shim-isnt-installed-to-efi
there is a 100 bounty on this question also

ok since no one responded on that bountied question I tried to understand the issue better by myself

I'll happily award you the 100 and upvote and accept you're answer if you can solve my issue

It is fine. You don't need certification or to pass all those checks to run Ubuntu. Surely you had to boot a live USB to run the tests in the first place, therefore showing you that Ubuntu does indeed work on your computer?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
